# Delete executables in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Before zipping and mailing a visual studio solution to a collaborator, I delete the executables and .dll files to prevent the mail from being bounced. I currently do this manually, but that is not very efficient since my solution may consist of a number of projects. Also, I sometimes delete the wrong files, including some .cs files.

Is there a way to delete all .dll and .exe files from the visual studio environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do a clean build:

```
Build -> Clean Solution
```

Comment: Is this possible in the visual studio c# 2010 express edition?

Comment: @willem - I don't believe this is an option in express.